# Should this usage of "since" be replaced by "from"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I don't know if the "since" in the following should be replaced by "from":

> The current increase in pledges from the EU -- as well as other countries, including the US and UK -- is aimed at keeping average global temperature rises within 1.5 degrees Celsius **since** pre-industrial levels and well below 2 degrees.

Comment: Yes, or probably even better, "... *of* pre-industrial levels."

Comment: @AndyBonner   Thank you. Is "since" wrong?

Comment: Yes; the word "since" probably came in because the author is thinking about the fact that these levels are in the past. But it isn't the right word for comparing numbers in a range like this: "The temperature is within 1.5 degrees **of** 30."

Comment: I think it should be reworded: ... keeping global temperature rise since pre-industrial times lower than 1.5 degrees Celsius.

Comment: ***of*** is best, but ***above*** would also be okay (much better than ***since***, at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct it should not be "since", but I don't think "from" is correct either. The appropriate word would be "of".

I wonder if this is an English translation of a non-English original; perhaps French? Idiomatic French often uses *depuis* where English uses *from*, but because the literal translation of *depuis* is *since* it's common to see the error if the French-to-English translation is done by a non-native-English speaker.

Another clue is the use of the word *rises* in:

> ... is aimed at keeping average global temperature rises ...

which is not idiomatic English either. I'd prefer to see the whole thing rewritten to something at least like the following:

> The current increase in pledges from the EU -- as well as other countries, including the US and UK -- is aimed at keeping average global temperature increases within 1.5 degrees Celsius of pre-industrial levels and well below 2 degrees.

But even there, it's not clear (to me; to someone more knowledgeable about climate change perhaps it's obvious) if what is being referred to are *annual* or *cumulative* figures. The use of the plural "increases" could suggest annual figures, but I suppose it might also refer to cumulative figures from various points on the globe.